# What UEFI-based machines are available in the market today?

Tags: firmware, uefi

I am looking for Client systems that have UEFI firmware. What are the existing systems that can be bought in the market today?

Comment: What do you mean by Client systems?   Desktops, laptops?

Answer (score 2):

IBM Blade-HS22 ,and  [x-series server](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/x/?cm_re=masthead-_-products-_-sys-xseries)

Answer (score 1):

My Mac Pro uses EFI -- I assume that's the same as UEFI?  (Seems to be from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Firmware_Interface )

Comment: Unfortunately no. Apple parted ways with EFI some years back, so the EFI they have is their own standard now. UEFI is for the rest of us.

Comment: So where does that leave one? No UEFY system at all?

Answer (score 1):

I think many HP and DELL laptops have UEFI, my Laptop (HP 6730s) has it.